# What does this quote by Anaïs Nin mean I think I know but I'm not sure

Tags: phrase-meaning

> There came a time when the risk to remain tight in the bud was more painful than the risk it took to blossom.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22tight+in+the+bud%22+Ana%C3%AFs+nin

Comment: Elizabeth Appell, AKA Lassie Benton, not Nin, though it's frequently attributed to Nin.

Comment: As a follow-up to Jon Hanna's comment above, I recommend that interested readers consult "[Who wrote 'Risk'? Is the Mystery Solved?](http://anaisninblog.skybluepress.com/2013/03/who-wrote-risk-is-the-mystery-solved/)" on The Anais Nin Blog.

Answer (score 2):

Here,
"remain tight in the bud" means staying where you are, keeping quiet, doing nothing, or not changing.
"took to blossom" means the opposite - moving on, speaking out, doing a deed, or changing.

So the time came when it was more difficult to do nothing than to change.

Comment: LOL :) Anais Nin writes erotica. Her statement has a very specific meaning :)

Comment: Ha, I must brush up on that genre. Can't say I'm familiar!

Comment: @barrycarter she wrote other fiction, literary criticism, memoir, and essays too, and her erotica was capable of metaphors more subtle than finding new ways to say "throbbing". Ronan's meaning is correct, though it could certainly say that and hint at the sort of meaning you allude to as subtext at the same time. Though actually, it was written by Elizabeth Appell and not by Nin at all, the attribution to Nin is perhaps so that by reputation it gains the erotic subtext it doesn't as readily manage on its own merits.

Answer (score 1):

To me, I think the phrase means the time you spent doing nothing hurts more than you trying to Blossom meaning growth